# how do i add value="1" to current li with wp_list_pages

Tags: php, css, wordpress

In my template on my wordpress i have a css menu slider but the pages are listed using the wordpress function wp_list_pages

i need to add value="1" to the current page that the user is on when im using wp_list_pages, whats the best way to do this?

the current code i am using is-

```
<?php wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order&depth=1&title_li=');?>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  To differentiate current page with others?

Comment: the jquery/css library adds and effect to the back of the links

Answer (score 1):

`wp_list_pages()` adds a class named `current_page_item`.  You can use this class to style current page item.  See here for more details - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages